# how to put join event button in my website

Tags: javascript, facebook

i have all the event links and now i just want to make joint button on my website so any one click on that joint button then login user status change for that particular event change to going. the previous website. i have one website that have this kind of button but i google many times with differet search but can not get join button.
the website have join button is https://imgoing.iti-marketing.com/#/peachtree/event/1143322699129386?_k=0v0t59.
 any one can give me any idea to make join button.

after three days of doing simple thing now i know what i am doing wrong
there are two type of {eventid}/attanding first get that give users that are coming in event second if we use post with this api then that will set rsvp to attanding
thanks buddy that comment and give me way to do this

Comment: That is not just a simple button; it triggers login to a Facebook app, and then rsvp-ing to the event is done via API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-rsvp_event

Comment: what is the API i should call for this when i have event id and user is login in facebook and my app?
i use {event}/attending

Comment: Should be a simple POST request to that same endpoint, using the user access token.